# hapijs-lab: Test a route with a valid session

Tags: node.js, hapi.js, hapi.js-lab

In my hapijs app I have few routes which require a `session`, uses `hapi-auth-cookie` plugin for auth strategy. I want to add few tests (via [Lab](https://github.com/hapijs/lab) ) for these routes.

I couldn't find any documentation on how I can setup a test (maybe via `before` ?) for this scenario. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can follow the @Gergo Erdosi example but this https://medium.com/the-spumko-suite/testing-hapi-services-with-lab-96ac463c490a worth a look as well.

Comment: Also this can help http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/97975/hapi-lab-e2e-test-workflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only need an authenticated user, just assign the user to the `credentials` property in tests:

```
var user = { ... };

server.inject({ method: 'GET', url: '/', credentials: user }, function (res) {
    console.log(res.result);
});
```

Here is an example that demonstrates it:

```
var Bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var Hapi = require('hapi');
var HapiAuthCookie = require('hapi-auth-cookie');

var server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({ port: 3000 });

var users = {
    john: {
        username: 'john',
        password: '$2a$10$iqJSHD.BGr0E2IxQwYgJmeP3NvhPrXAeLSaGCj6IR/XU5QtjVu5Tm',
        name: 'John Doe',
        id: '2133d32a'
    }
};

var validate = function (request, username, password, callback) {
    var user = users[username];
    if (!user) {
        return callback(null, false);
    }

    Bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function (err, isValid) {
        callback(err, isValid, { id: user.id, name: user.name });
    });
};

server.register(HapiAuthCookie, function (err) {
    server.auth.strategy('session', 'cookie', {
        password: 'secret',
        validateFunc: validate
    });

    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/',
        config: {
            auth: 'session',
            handler: function (request, reply) {
                reply('hello, ' + request.auth.credentials.name);
            }
        }
    });

    server.inject({ method: 'GET', url: '/', credentials: users.john }, function (res) {
        console.log(res.result);
    });
});
```

*Large part of the example was taken from the [Authentication Tutorial](http://hapijs.com/tutorials/auth).*

Comment: Adding `credentials` to the `server.inject` options worked!

Comment: It's now `auth: { credentials: users.john }` instead of `credentials`

Answer (score 1):

For my need for session during testing, I created [hapi-session-inject](https://github.com/vinkaga/hapi-session-inject). Usage is as follows

```
const server = new Hapi.Server();
const session = new Session(server);

// Callback interface
session.inject('/', (res) => {
    ...
});

// Promise interface
return session.inject('/').then((res) => {
    ...
});
```

Hope it helps.